# How to change the current displayed window from another thread? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, invoke

I have a client-server application (Trivia Game).

My problem is:
When the clients are in a "waitingRoom" the program starts a separate thread that asks the server for the game's state every second (in order to see if any other client has joined, to see if the game started or if the admin closed the room).

In my case, when the admin shuts the room, all clients need to return to the menu screen. The separate thread receives a message that tells him to close the room and now the thread needs to change the currently displayed window.

I've tried to use Dispatcher.Invoke but no success:

```
public void returnToMenuScreen()
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        this.IsEnabled = false;

        Menu newScreen = new Menu(Globals.SOCKET, Globals.USER);
        newScreen.Show();
    });
}
```

Globals.SOCKET : (Socket)
Globals.USER : (string)

EDIT: This code doesn't work and the error I receive is that other thread (main) ownes the property.

2nd EDIT:

```
public void displayPlayers(string players)
{
    //spliting all the names.
    string[] names = players.Split(", ".ToCharArray());

    //Removing The un-updated list.
    playersListBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => playersListBox.Items.Clear()));

    //Displaying the names.
    foreach (string name in names)
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            playersListBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => playersListBox.Items.Add(name)));
}
```

this code does work, I change the items in a currently displayed listBox.

Comment: Are you sure that `Dispatcher` belongs to the same thread as your UI?

Comment: I used Dispatcher to add new clients to a listBox that is in the currently displayed window, so yes, I assume.

Comment: @Andy , look at my second edit

Comment: Without a good [mcve] it's not possible to know for sure what the problem is. And this is exacerbated by the lack of an exact quote of the exception type and message. However, certainly the `Dispatcher` property you're using in the first example does not match the thread that owns the other properties you're trying to set. Why is this? Who knows. All that said, for this type of scenario I generally don't do explicit thread management. Instead, use data templating to define the content of your main window based on the program state, and instead of fiddling with the UI directly, ...

Comment: ... just change the view model object based on that program state, so that the window is showing the right template. As long as you stick to just updating view model properties (including e.g. a property that references the sub-view model that goes with the current state), WPF will manage the cross-thread marshaling for you, and you won't have to worry about which dispatcher owns what at all.